# How to populate a map in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, basex

I have an XML file in the following [link](http://expirebox.com/download/3eb64bcb5a820ad8012ce65ca59d60e3.html)

I want to populate a map that with ids of movies and the average of their corresponding ratings. I am trying the following command from this [site](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/hashtable#id_61683)

```
for $doc in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie
let $map:= map:map()
let $key := map:put($map, $doc/@id, avg($doc/ratings/child::node()))
return $map
```

However, it doesn't run. I get an exception, `Expecting variable declaration`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I am trying it the following command

```
let $map:=map{}
for $doc in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie
return
map:put($map,  
  $doc/@id,avg($doc/ratings/child::node())
)
```

I get seperate maps

Comment: It should be noted that the _map_ you are referring to is specific to MarkLogic and has nothing to do with a map as introduced by XQuery 3.1.

Comment: @dirkk I am trying this out in basex.

Comment: @dirkk Please check the updated desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in my comment, the map syntax MarkLogic uses has nothing to do with the XQuery 3.1 term `map`. MarkLogic implemented this map structure before the official XQuery spec defined it (this structure is rather new). So you can use the map as documented in the MarkLogic docs only when you use MarkLogic, it is a proprietary extension.

On the other hand, BaseX supports the XQuery 3.1 construct `map`. Therefore you should follow what is [documented at the BaseX documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Map_Module). And this makes it actually shorter and side-effect free. You could e.g. do:

```
map:merge(for $movie in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie return map:entry($movie/@id, avg($movie/ratings/child::node())))
```

You could also use `map:put`, but it doesn't make much sense for this use case as you would create a new map each time you call the `map:put()` function.